# Can I upload online bank statements from my bank showing internal use only for my Canada visa application?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

Can I upload the PDF bank statements showing internal use only requested from my bank for a Canada visa application?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "internal use only"?

Comment: Also, almost obligatory pointer to [Gayot Fow's excellent explanation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/40603) about bank statements submitted with visa applications - while written the context of a UK visa, I think it holds true universally.

Comment: Is this a ‘normal’ (eg regular monthly statement), or just something akin to a list of (recent) transactions? I’d say ‘yes’ if the former but ‘no’ if the latter.

Comment: @Sabine That answer by Gayot Fow truly is excellent.  RIP Gayot Fow